# How to connect to Spark EMR from the locally running Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark

I have created a Spark EMR cluster. I would like to execute jobs either on my localhost or EMR cluster.

Assuming I run spark-shell on my local computer how can I tell it to connect to the Spark EMR cluster, what would be the exact configuration options and/or commands to run.

Comment: I guess you have to ssh to your EMR cluster and submit spark code.

Comment: @WoodChopper, thanks. I am able to ssh to EMR cluster and submit code from there with no problems. I was wondering if it's possible to submit code from localhost Spark shell directly to the remote EMR cluster.

Comment: I think unless your local machine is master node for cluster you cannot do that. In case of EMR it is apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like others have also failed at this and ended up running the Spark driver on EMR, but then making use of e.g. Zeppelin or Jupyter running on EMR.

> Setting up our own machines as spark drivers that connected to the core nodes on EMR would have been ideal. Unfortunately, this was impossible to do and we forfeited after trying many configuration changes. The driver would start up and then keep waiting unsuccessfully, trying to connect to the slaves.
>
> Most of our Spark development is on pyspark using Jupyter Notebook as our IDE. Since we had to run Jupyter from the master node, we couldn’t risk losing our work if the cluster were to go down. So, we created an EBS volume and attached it to the master node and placed all of our work on this volume. [...]

[source](https://www.trulia.com/blog/tech/aws-emr-ad-hoc-spark-development-environment/)

Note: If you go down this route, I would consider using S3 for storing notebooks, then you don't have to manage EBS volumes.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to add your spark job as an EMR step to your EMR cluster. For this, you need [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) installed on your local computer
(see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) for installation guide), and your jar file on s3.

Once you have aws cli, assuming your spark class to run is `com.company.my.MySparkJob` and your jar file is located on s3 at `s3://hadi/my-project-0.1.jar`, you can run the following command from your terminal:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-************* --steps Type=spark,Name=My_Spark_Job,Args=[-class,com.company.my.MySparkJob,s3://hadi/my-project-0.1.jar],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```